# How to use model architecture of pretrained models but no weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet, pre-trained-model

I want to use ResNet model architecture and want to change last few layers; how can I only use model architecture from model zoo in Tensorflow?

Comment: How do you want to change the last few layers? I recommend using `tf.keras.applications.ResNet50` and setting the `weights` parameters to be `None` as a first step.

Comment: Okay, also how can I only get the convolution base and change classifier completely?

Comment: I will set top include as false but I want to see the architecture of the base layer by layer in the summary

Answer (score 1):

To use a ResNet model, you can choose a select few from `tensorflow.keras.applications` including `ResNet50`, `ResNet101`, and `ResNet152`. Then, you will need to change a few of the default arguments if you want to do transfer learning. For your question, you will need to set the `weights` parameter equal to `None`. Otherwise, `'imagenet'` weights are provided. Also, you need to set `include_top` to be `False` since the number of classes for your problem will likely be different from ImageNet. Finally, you will need to provide the shape of your data in `input_shape`. This would look something like this.

```
base = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=shape)
```

To get a summary of the model, you can do

```
base.summary()
```

To add your own head, you can use the Functional API. You will need to add an `Input` layer and your own `Dense` layer which will correspond to your task. This could be

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=shape)
base = base(input)
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(base)
```

Finally, to construct a model, you can do

```
model = tf.keras.models.Model(input, out)
```

The `Model` constructor takes 2 arguments. The first being the inputs to your model, and the second being the outputs. Note that calling `model.summary()` will show the ResNet base as a separate layer. To view all layers of the ResNet base, you can do `model.layers[1].summary()`, or you can modify the code on how you built your model. The second way would be

```
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(base.output)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(base.input, out)
```

Now you can view all layers with just `model.summary()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
inp_sh = (256,256,3) # for examples
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,
                             input_shape=inp_sh)
CLASSES = 2
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalMaxPooling2D(name='max_pool')(x) # or avarage pooling
out = Dense(CLASSES , activation='softmax')(x)
mdl = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=out)
mdl.summary()
```